# Why is my MS Access database always broken?

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

I wrote a program running as a service that need to frequently gain access to MS Access database. After a period of time, my program exits automatically, then I open my MS Access database with Office, it says it is broken!

It seems very strange as my program do just some very common database access: insert, select and delete. Why is it always broken after running a period of time?

Has anyone here ever run into such problem? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Do you close the DB connection gracefully during the "automatic exit"?

Comment: i think you really need to post an error message of some kind.

Comment: Please define broken, is the database corrupted? Does the app fail on every insert or update?

Comment: Hi, JTew! My Access database is corrupted, even Office cannot open it.

Comment: Agree with many of the the thoughts here.  A question in my head is how do you terminate the service, and does it terminate gracefully?  For example if you use service control to stop the service and it fails to stop in the allotted time, service control manager kills the process.

Answer (score 5):

Almost all problems of this nature when dealing with Access (or Excel, Outlook...) are due to not correctly releasing (i.e. cleaning up) resources.

Suggest you post any errors you are seeing.

Answer (score 3):

Access does not recover gracefully if a program terminates without closing the database.  There is a dirty flag that Access uses, and the repair feature will reset it (amongst other things), but typically, I don't recommend Access where any robust handling is required.

Comment: Hi Cade! Thanks for your quick reply!
Are you meaning the problem is caused because the program hasn't close the database. Are there any other possible reasons for this problem? I have no other choice except MS Access as our project is based on MS Access database.

Comment: Yes, if the program doesn't close the database.  Also if the network connection is lost while the file is opened.  Also, this might not be caused by your service, but some other program or another instance of your program opening the database and not closing it properly.